# How to get valid ODBC connection string from Microsoft Windows "ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit)" - Firebird case?

Tags: powerbi, odbc, firebird

I have installed Firebird ODBC driver on my computer and I have entered data for the new connection inside Microsoft Windows "ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit)" and "Test Connection" was successful and I can also use this DSN (Data Source Name) from Power BI Desktop.

But now I am trying to use Firebird ODBC driver from other application (custom M Language connector, that works atop Firebird ODBC driver and that I develop to enable DirectQuery access mode in Power BI Desktop, ODBC drivers natively does not support DirectQuery access mode) and there I am required to provide ODBC connection string as one string.

I have formed (more or less intuitively) such string, e.g.:

```
User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database=D:\DB\ERP.FDB;DataSource=192.168.1.3;Port=3050;Dialect=3;Charset=UTF8;Role=;Connection lifetime=15;Pooling=true;MinPoolSize=0;MaxPoolSize=50;Packet Size=8192;ServerType=0;Initial Catalog=test;
```

But this string is rejected by Power BI Desktop with error message:

```
Unable to connect
We encountered an error while trying to connect.
Details: "ODBC: ERROR [08004] [ODBC Firebird Driver]connection lost to database
ERROR [01S00] [ODBC Firebird Driver]Invalid connection string attribute
ERROR [01S00] [ODBC Firebird Driver]Invalid connection string attribute"
```

My intention and wish is to grab already existing ODBC connection string that sits inside "ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit)" and use it for my connection, but the problem is that "ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit)" does not provide easily accessible way to get such fully formatted connection string from DSN entry.

So, my question is: how to read connection string from "ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit)" DSN entry. Specifically, how to do it from page that is used for Firebird ODBC driver.

Answer (score 2):

You should read https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fbodbc20/firebird-odbc-driver-20-manual.html#fbodbc205-connection

If you already have configured DSN, you don't need anything else, just use "`DSN=xxxx;`".